# References are not appearing in first frame

Tags: beamer, bibliographies

I am preparing my presentation using Beamer. While running the file, in the output especially in the reference frame (there are 93 references) in the first frame reference 1 is appearing and 2,3,4 is disappearing where as reference 5 to 93 is continuously appearing in all frames. Please give me the solution for this.

I am using the code as shown below.

```
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{}
\textbf{References:}
\begin{enumerate}

\bibitem{1Aki}
J. Akiyama, T. Hamada, I. Yoshimura, On characterizations of the middle graphs, TRU Mathematics 11 (1975) pp, 35-39.

\bibitem{2Alsp}
B. Alspach, C.C.Chen, Kevin McAvaney, On a class of Hamiltonian laceable 3-regular graphs, Disc. Math. 151 (1996) pp 19-38.

\bibitem{3Alsp}
B. Alspach, C.Q. Zhang, Hamilton cycles in cubic Cayley graphs on dihedral groups, Ars Combin. 28 (1989), pp 101-108.

\bibitem{4Anad}
B.S. Anand, M. Changat, S. Klavzar, I. Peterin, Convex sets in lexicographic products of graphs, Graphs Combin. 28 (2012), 77-84.

\bibitem{5Basa}
M. Basavaraju, L.S. Chandran, D. Rajendraprasad, A. Ramaswamy, Rainbow connection number of graph power and graph products,  arXiv:1104.4190v1 [math.co] (2011).

\bibitem{6Beh}
M. Behzad, G Chartrand, Total graphs and traversability, Proc. Edinburgh Math. Soc. (2) 15 (1966/67), pp 117-120.

\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
```

---

Full example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{hyperref,times,graphicx,setspace}
\mode<presentation>
   {
    \usetheme{Warsaw}
%  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
    }
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{times}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{epsfig,amsmath,amsthm,latexsym,amssymb,amsgen,graphicx}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{eg}[thm]{Example}
\newtheorem{ex}[thm]{Exercise}
\newtheorem{prob}{Problem}
\newtheorem{ob}[thm]{Observation}
\newtheorem{rk}[thm]{Remark}
\newtheorem{ill}{Illustration}
\newtheorem{con}{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{pf}{Proof}
\newtheorem*{pfc}{Proof ctd...}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
%\newenvironment{daln}{$\arraycolsep=.2ex\begin{array}[t]{rl}}%
%{\end{array}$}
\setlength{\unitlength}{0.1mm}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}

\title[XXXXXX]
{\it{\bf{XXXXXXXX}}}



\author[K.SRINIVASA RAO] % (optional, use only with lots of authors)
{ K.SRINIVASA RAO}
\institute[]
{\\RESEARCH GUIDE \vskip .5cm
{\large XXXX}


\subject{Ph.D Viva-Voce}



\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}

\date{--- --,--}



\begin{document}


\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{}
\textbf{References:}
\begin{enumerate}

\bibitem{1Aki}
J. Akiyama, T. Hamada, I. Yoshimura, On characterizations of the middle graphs, TRU Mathematics 11 (1975) pp, 35-39.

\bibitem{2Alsp}
B. Alspach, C.C.Chen, Kevin McAvaney, On a class of Hamiltonian laceable 3-regular graphs, Disc. Math. 151 (1996) pp 19-38.

\bibitem{3Alsp}
B. Alspach, C.Q. Zhang, Hamilton cycles in cubic Cayley graphs on dihedral groups, Ars Combin. 28 (1989), pp 101-108.

\bibitem{4Anad}
B.S. Anand, M. Changat, S. Klavzar, I. Peterin, Convex sets in lexicographic products of graphs, Graphs Combin. 28 (2012), 77-84.

\bibitem{5Basa}
M. Basavaraju, L.S. Chandran, D. Rajendraprasad, A. Ramaswamy, Rainbow connection number of graph power and graph products,  arXiv:1104.4190v1 [math.co] (2011).

\bibitem{6Beh}
M. Behzad, G Chartrand, Total graphs and traversability, Proc. Edinburgh Math. Soc. (2) 15 (1966/67), pp 117-120.

\bibitem{7Beh}
M. Behzad, A criterion for the planarity of the total graph of a graph, Proc. Cambridge Philos. Soc. 63 (1967), pp 679-681.

\bibitem{8Beh}
M. Behzad, The connectivity of total graphs, Austr. Math. Bull. 1 (1969), pp 175-181.

\bibitem{9Beh}
M. Behzad, a characterization of total graphs, Amer. Math. Soc. 26 (3), (1970), pp 383-389.

\bibitem{10Benk}
Beineke, Derived graphs and digraphs. Beiträge zur Graphentheorie (H. Sachs, H. Voss, and H. Walther, eds.) Teubner, Leipzig 1968, pp 17-33.

\bibitem{11Berm}
J.C. Bermond, N. Homobono, C. Peyrat, Connectivity of Kautz networks, Disc. Math. 114 (1993), pp 51-62.


\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please make a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)? If I just add basic things (like a document class) to your code, I get references 1-5 on the first slide, and 6. on the second slide.

Comment: If I compile same code I am getting the same result but if I use title and other information I am not getting references in proper way.

Answer (score 2):

The central problem is `\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}`, just remove it.

Some minor problems/comments:

- You don't need `hyperref`, `graphicx`, `color` with beamer
- don't load the same package multiple times, e.g. `times`, `graphicx`, `amsthm` etc.
- missing `}` at the end of your institute
- missing `\end{enumerate}`

---

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usepackage[english]{babel}


%\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
  \frametitle{References:}
  \begin{enumerate}
        \bibitem{1Aki}
        J. Akiyama, T. Hamada, I. Yoshimura, On characterizations of the middle graphs, TRU Mathematics 11 (1975) pp, 35-39.

        \bibitem{2Alsp}
        B. Alspach, C.C.Chen, Kevin McAvaney, On a class of Hamiltonian laceable 3-regular graphs, Disc. Math. 151 (1996) pp 19-38.

        \bibitem{3Alsp}
        B. Alspach, C.Q. Zhang, Hamilton cycles in cubic Cayley graphs on dihedral groups, Ars Combin. 28 (1989), pp 101-108.

        \bibitem{4Anad}
        B.S. Anand, M. Changat, S. Klavzar, I. Peterin, Convex sets in lexicographic products of graphs, Graphs Combin. 28 (2012), 77-84.

        \bibitem{5Basa}
        M. Basavaraju, L.S. Chandran, D. Rajendraprasad, A. Ramaswamy, Rainbow connection number of graph power and graph products,  arXiv:1104.4190v1 [math.co] (2011).

        \bibitem{6Beh}
        M. Behzad, G Chartrand, Total graphs and traversability, Proc. Edinburgh Math. Soc. (2) 15 (1966/67), pp 117-120.

        \bibitem{7Beh}
        M. Behzad, A criterion for the planarity of the total graph of a graph, Proc. Cambridge Philos. Soc. 63 (1967), pp 679-681.

        \bibitem{8Beh}
        M. Behzad, The connectivity of total graphs, Austr. Math. Bull. 1 (1969), pp 175-181.

        \bibitem{9Beh}
        M. Behzad, a characterization of total graphs, Amer. Math. Soc. 26 (3), (1970), pp 383-389.

        \bibitem{10Benk}
        Beineke, Derived graphs and digraphs. Beiträge zur Graphentheorie (H. Sachs, H. Voss, and H. Walther, eds.) Teubner, Leipzig 1968, pp 17-33.

        \bibitem{11Berm}
        J.C. Bermond, N. Homobono, C. Peyrat, Connectivity of Kautz networks, Disc. Math. 114 (1993), pp 51-62.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) You should write the definite 'Hitchhiker's Guide to Beamer' and/or collaborate with @JosephWright to maintain Beamer

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks for your kind words! I'm not sure if I would be helpful, he seems to deal very well with the multitude of packages he has.